# Count all rows by status

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.4

I want to use this table to store tickets in PostgreSQL.

```
CREATE TABLE TICKET(
 ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
 TITLE TEXT,
 STATUS INTEGER,
 LAST_UPDATED DATE,
 CREATED DATE
)
;
```

I use column 'status' to set diffrent status(1, 2, 3, 4). How I can count all tickets by status with one SQL query?

I would like to see the final result for example like simple array of numbers:

```
34, 44, 64, 23
```

Comment: Do a GROUP BY, use count(*).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Select status, count(*)
from Ticket
group by status
```

If you have to show status without any tickets also. Then I would follow the below steps.
there will be a table to store status details.With out the same we can't know which status is missing in Ticket table

Let say the table is status as below

```
CREATE TABLE _STATUS(
  STATUS INTEGER,
 STATUS_NAME TEXT
)
;

CREATE TABLE TICKET(
 ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
 TITLE TEXT,
 STATUS INTEGER,
 LAST_UPDATED DATE,
 CREATED DATE
)
;
```

The query will be

```
select  s.status,COUNT(t.*)
from _status t left join ticket t
on s.status = t.status
group by s.status
```

Comment: Yes, it works but if I have no tickets with status 4 I get empty result. Probably I will get NPE in Java. How I can get status even when I have no tiuckets with status 4?

Comment: do u have a seperate status table? or 1,2,3,4 are fixed?

Comment: It's fixed into one table column - status.

Comment: Can I ask one addition question. It' turns out that it will be much more yesy to create java object if I get he result this way ` 32 21 32 12`. Can you show me example of a query with this result, please?

Comment: @peterpenzov didn't understand

Comment: Can you modify the query to return simple something like simple array of numbers?

Comment: Done, see the post.

Answer (score 3):

```
select status, count(*) from ticket group by status
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select status, count(*) from ticket group by status;
```

Comment: Can you show me example for a query which gets this result  `32 21 32 12` please?

Comment: Not sure if I understand

Answer (score 1):

If you want the values on one row, something like:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN status=1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as '1',
  COUNT(CASE WHEN status=2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as '2',
  COUNT(CASE WHEN status=3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as '3',
  COUNT(CASE WHEN status=4 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as '4'
FROM TICKET;
```

But then you will have to keep your SQL updated with any new status codes.

Comment: This is not answer. Question is  "How I can count all tickets by status", but not "Select in one row"

Comment: It is exactly what what was asked. OP wanted the result in one row, indicated by his example. He further emphasised this with his comment to another solution, "It' turns out that it will be much more yesy to create java object if I get he result this way ` 32 21 32 12`. Can you show me example of a query with this result, please?". Then again in another with, "Can you show me example for a query which gets this result 32 21 32 12 please?"